# Can we create a three handle HTML range slider without using jQuery ui

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, slider

Can we create a three handle range slider in js, without the use of JQuery UI?.

If so can you please share a link to the demo, or provide a sample code for the same.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Well of course you can create it. Just use javascript. That's what jQuery UI uses.

Comment: The title says 'without', yet the post says 'with'. As was mentioned, yes, you can create anything you want with scripting. Would advise you supply a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  it can be done (anything with jquery can be accomplished with regular javascript). Try downloading an unminified JQuery UI and find how it is done in there if you want to replicate it from scratch.